# Packing my EXE and runtime folder (created by Excelsior JET) into one single executable?

Tags: java, exe

I am using Excelsior JET to convert my JAR into an EXE.

I want my application to be Standalone. Literally one single file without needing installation. JET creates an EXE and also a runtime folder.

The solution, according to them, is to use 7z to create a self-extracting file (into a temporary) that will run the application.

The problem is that the self-extraction takes a long time, so program startup is ridiculous.

So my question is: is there another alternative to pack my EXE and runtime into a single standalone file?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap up my jars as .exe - works fine for me so far. I read about how people managed to wrap the JRE into the file using launch4j in this post:

[How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j)

hope that helps - never tried myself...

Comment: Yeah well, the reason I am using Excelsior Jet is because it compiles your JAR into native code (so ultimately the program is not Java). Launch4j just wraps the JAR (the JVM is still used). The problem is that the resulting EXE is accompanied by a runtime folder (and I want to distribute only one file).

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I work for Excelsior.

There were some changes made in Java 8 aimed at enabling the creation of standalone executables, such as [JEP-178](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/178). It was unfeasible for us to implement this feature ourselves for earlier versions of Java. That said, we have only moved to Java 8 in Sep'15, and standalone executables are not in our near- to mid-term plans due to (relatively) low customer demand.