# Make Installer of java Application

Tags: java, installation

I have tried this two setup for making installer of java application.

1. Exe4j
2. Inno setup

I have used these 2 setups for making a java application installer.but when I installed on another operating system (Microsoft OS) windows 7 or 8 then its gives error No JVM could be found on your system...

I am stuck in for 2 days.

java application store data into 2 text file and then on text file generate at run time and then delete generated file after some processing. I don't know how should I generate a setup for java application....please anyone?

Comment: First check if JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is present on the windows machine. If YES then Check if JAVA_HOME (pointing to your JRE bin) is set in the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html). It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X and can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one

Comment: i still have a same problem i have maked a exe by launch4j but its give an error on different machine no jre????

Comment: See [how to bundle a jre with launch4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j) for an example how to include jre. Also make sure that `<bundledJreAsFallback>` is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

We also have a feature in Advanced Installer, Java edition, that can be used to package your [Java application for Windows](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html) and for [Mac OS.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-multiple-builds.html#mac-build)

Here is a [1 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NrpxczsF6A) that shows how easy it is to build your installer.

Advanced Installer also has the ability to bundle a specific JRE version inside your installer, so your application will use only that JRE, no matter if on the end user machine there is another version of JRE or none at all.