# To distribute my java program as an application with jre to my client

Tags: java, deployment, inno-setup, launch4j

I have completed my project and now i want to deploy it. i have converted jar to exe using launch4j and created a setup using inno setup compiler. Now my problem is when i run this application in other system it asks for JRE. i have tried all possible solutions from stackoverflow but couldnt get the solution yet.I want to distribute my application that even runs in System which does not have JRE. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may package your application in a zip with the JRE, as explained in another similar question: [How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j)

Then, in launch4j, refer to the JRE with a relative path.

Comment: i tried this. still it asks for jre

Comment: true, this solution works, but still involves an unpacked  jre on the client.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot run a java project without JRE

Comment: It is clear from the question that the OP already knows this.