# How do I bundle a JRE in my JAR, so that it can run on systems without Java?

Tags: java, bundle, exe, packaging, maven-shade-plugin

I want to bundle a JRE inside my executable JAR, so that the exe can run on any system.

I have tried [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), but that approach requires me to ship both the JRE and the exe. As per my requirements, I should not use an installer to ship, nor extract/install the JRE on the client machine.

How do I put a JRE inside a JAR and make use of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j?rq=1

Answer (score 21):

You cannot put a JRE inside a JAR file.  (Well you can ... but it won't help.)

What you need to do is build and distribute an installer.  Prior to Java 9, the recommended way to create an installer is to use a commercial or open-source installer generator.  (Google will help you find one.)

It is also possible to do embed a JRE in a ZIP file, as described here:

- [How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j) (see the accepted answer)

The ZIP file contains the JRE and the application JAR, and other files that it needs.  The user has to unzip the ZIP file to install the application.

---

> .. but it's copying total JRE in client system of almost 100 MB.  Is it possible to make JRE light weight?

Not really.  The most (legal) light-weight way to distribute a JRE is to distribute an Oracle Java installer.  Beware that the Java Binary License forbids the distribution of a cut-down JRE.  If you want to go down that path *talk to a lawyer first!!*

---

Distributing Java apps with an embedded JRE is arguably a bad thing:

- It fills up the user's disk with multiple JREs.
- The JREs tend to be hidden away / not visible to normal security updates / patching / audits.  Hence they tend to become a security liability.
- You need to regularly update your distributables ... to avoid foisting out-of-date / insecure JREs on the unsuspecting user.

---

From Java 9 onwards there is a better solution than including a standard JRE in your installer.  Use the new `jlink` utility to create a tailored JRE for your application; see https://www.baeldung.com/jlink for a tutorial, and the Oracle [Jlink manual entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm).

Note that `jlink` addresses the concerns with embedded JREs that we mentioned above.  But it **clearly makes it your responsibility<sup>1</sup>** to provide JVM security patches to your users in the form of new jlink'd distributables.

From Java 14 onwards you can use `jpackager` to create an installer or installable for your application.  This will include an embedded JRE and a custom launcher.

Finally, you could consider using GraalVM to generate a executable binary for application.

<sup>1 - In reality, it has *always* been an application supplier / vendor's responsibility to advise and assist customers in upgrading embedded JREs.  Unfortunately, many vendors neglected this, leading to customers running applications with known Java vulnerabilities, and Sun/Oracle getting the blame ... unfairly ... for the vendor's failings.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It did work for me with launch4j

first create an app folder
then open launch4j and type in the jar file, output file (should be in the app folder), and the icon (please have it in app folder). then go to the jre part and type jre-{version ur using} in the bundled jre paths then put option only use private jdk runtimes then put the min version to ur java version, then go the jdk installation and copy the bin and lib folder then create a jre-{version ur using} folder then paste these in. Then compile it into exe!

Answer (score -6):

Late better than never. I used maven-shade-plugin in the pom.xml as follows:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
          <configuration>
              <transformers>
                  <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                  <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                  </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <!-- If false the shaded artifact takes the normal artifact name, such as,  "core-tools-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"-->
              <!-- Meanwhile, another non-shaded version takes the prefix Original, such as  "Original-core-tools-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"-->
            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <!-- Exclude signed Manifests from the UberJar -->
              <filters>
                  <filter>
                      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                      <excludes>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                  </filter>
                  <filter>
                      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                      <includes>
                          <include>sun/misc/**</include>
                      </includes>
                  </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked.  A shaded JAR doesn't contain an embedded JRE.

Comment: So ... in this case ... better never than later with an off-topic answer.