# Open Jar without using java -jar with args

Tags: java, macos, shell

I am using a jar to run some code as a helper for a program (OSX). I want to open this jar programmatically, and have been using a ProcessBuilder to run it through the terminal.

However, I want to give the jar some arguments (specifically a file location, but that's irrelevant). I have using `java -jar jarName arg`, but this doesn't work with people who don't have Java tools installed.

I have tried to use `open jarName --args arg`, but the jar doesn't recognize the args. 
As a test, I am just using the following code for now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      // set a PrintStream to see the args presented
      System.setOut(
        new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/argsTest.txt"))));
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println(argsSize: "+args.length");

   for (String s : args)
      System.out.println(s);
}
```

I am fine with trying other methods of opening jars, so long as they are available on all up to date systems.

I have the JRE packaged in the application, is there a way to use that?

Comment: You need Java installed to run a jar

Comment: JDKs for Java 9 and later include the `jmod` and `jlink` tools which let you create a self-contained tree (called an “image”) which has an executable file which runs the program.  A jlink’d image does not require the user to have Java installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle jre with with your program. Refer to [Bundle JRE along with executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983169/bundle-jre-along-with-executable-jar)

or if you are using netbeans - it will allow you to test it first. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html

how to run - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#check

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverFlow!

Sadly, the answer is **no, you can't do this**. If you want to run some java code, from a jar or not, you will **need** to have java installed on the machine. Specifically, you need the JRE to have the JVM.

But you can provide java by your own when deploying your app. See this threads:

- https://superuser.com/questions/745112/how-do-i-run-a-jar-file-without-installing-java
- [Running java without installing jre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371535/running-java-without-installing-jre)

for more informations.

Comment: I have a JRE packaged in the application... is there a way to run the jar using that?

Comment: If you really have a jre packaged, you should be able to use the `java` command line tool. Just look at the installation folder of the jre, you should find the file `bin/java.exe`. Be careful to set the PATH variable so that your program find the java binary!