# How can I add dependencies to my final .jar file (Netbeans 12)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm working on my first swing app, and after a big headache and research I ended up here, as I said, I did a lot of research and tried many things but unfortunately nothing worked for me

In netbeans everything works correctly and I have no issues, and also when I clean and build the project, the problem is when I send the `.jar` file to a friend. He can't open it, only if he have `JDK 16` installed

I'm wondering if it's a problem with libraries not building correctly or something

I tried adding this plugin to `pom.xml`:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>NewJFrame</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44983322/2478398 answer your question?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a ```lib``` folder after I clean and build the project, where can I get or how can I create the ```lib``` folder correctly?