# How to run Java project on local without any program?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project. How can I make the java spring boot project run on my local machine without using any application (Intellij IDEA, Eclipse, Heroku, Docker etc.)? I can do this using jar file on command line, but I want to use a different method. How can I do that on windows ?

Comment: What different method are you wanting to use?  Shortcut?

Comment: It can be any method but not the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: ok, then a shortcut?

Comment: Shortcut on a IDE ?

Comment: And what is your project's build like? Is it maven or gradle? Assuming its maven you can just need to execute `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: No, the shortcut would be targeting the java executable in the JRE, and your JAR (or wherever your class files are) would be a parameter to the shortcut. Someone did it here: https://superuser.com/questions/975687/how-to-pin-an-executable-jar-to-start-in-windows-10

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick That would violate his command line constraint.

Comment: Is the OP completely excluding the option of running from commandline or just not willing to use the old vanilla way of executing the jar as opposed to the Springboot maven plugin way?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options, depending on how advanced you want to make it.

Here's a related answer on how to use Launch4J:
[How do I bundle a JRE in my JAR, so that it can run on systems without Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983169/how-do-i-bundle-a-jre-in-my-jar-so-that-it-can-run-on-systems-without-java)

You can also look into using https://www.advancedinstaller.com, which allows helps you create installation wizards for different operating systems, including setting registry values, etc.

Comment: I can't use any program. I have only a pc and a spring boot project.

Comment: So you want to be able to run the service in the JAR, but without:
- opening a terminal
- creating an executable (.exe)?

Maybe a .bat script?

Comment: I have only project on my hand. So you can't use the methods what as I wrote above. You can open the terminal and you can do something on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JRE is installed on your machine (which is the case if you're running `.jar` files from `cmd`) then open the jar file as any windows program, if you want to generate an executable `.exe` from your file then use launch4j.

Comment: But I don't want to use any program.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run the file without the JRE installed ? That's impossible unless you wrap it inside your file using launch4j.

Comment: Sounds like the JRE is installed. He can run it using command line.

Comment: That's what i said in my answer, i guess he struggles locating the jar file in his build directory.

Answer (score 0):

### GraalVM

Another more modern and efficient approach than launch4j would be to use GraalVM.

- Install GraalVM
- Install some C developer environment like Visual Studio
- Run: `gu install native-image`

After compiling your Java code with `javac` compile as a **native image**

- `javac YourClass.java`
- `native-image YourClass`

Now you have an efficient executable that can run on its own anywhere.

*At least this is how you do it manually.*

You have a library for Spring, `spring-native`, to help you. Or you can develop your project using Quarkus instead, which can build a native image out of the box