# What is a possible, handy way to build a project with Maven which uses an embedded JRE?

Tags: java, maven

I want my program to be usable by systems which do not have a JRE preinstalled.

What I'm a little bit struggling with right now is how can I tell Maven to use an embedded JRE and not the system JRE? Right now to build my application I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin along with the maven-nativedependencies-plugin to resolve native dependencies and the maven-jar-plugin.

My understanding in theory is somewhat of the following:

1. Copy(?) JRE into my project folder (e.g. a folder with java8)
2. Zip everything up (Somehow included in my build process)
3. Tell Maven to use the included JRE
4. User can unpack and does not need a preinstalled JRE

I assume that I somehow need to tell maven/my application to unpack that shipped JRE and use it? I already read about the Java 9 Deployment guide (I'm using Java8 though) and jlink'ed images, however all of it seems a little bit tricky and I'm not build process expert.

Could anyone share their experiences / thoughts on that topic?

Comment: Maven is a build tool, once built you shouldn't be using maven to execute your application.

Comment: Valid point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to build an executable image:

1. If you are on Java 9 you can use [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9) to build an executable runtime image.
2. Use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) tool to include JRE e.g. [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582064/1602555).
3. Include JRE as a Maven dependency and repackage with assembly plugin. Do note that this dependency is quite outdated.

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle.java</groupId>
     <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.0_131</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Including the JRE as Maven dependency sounds promising to me. Could you maybe elaborate a little bit on what you mean with "repackage with assembly plugin" (simply run a build process)? If the user has unpacked the folder and is executing the JAR how does it know that it has to use the JRE shipped in the folder?

Comment: It's an outdated JRE from 2017-04-18 and there is no promise that Oracle will ever release a new version. I really woudln't invest into this approach. You can use `maven-dependency-plugin:unpack` to extract whatever files are part of this dependency and then `maven-assembly-plugin` to build a runtime archive.

Comment: So you would rather recommened to go with launch4j?

Comment: Personally I'd assume that tools shipped with the JDK e.g. `jlink` and `jdeps` is the best approach if you can use JDK9 or JDK10.

Comment: I also read about jsmooth, seems to be similiar to launch4j, maybe you could add it to your answer for completeness: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/