# Launch4j:This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161 using maven?

Tags: java, maven, ant, bundle, launch4j

I am using the launch4j maven plugin to generate an .exe for my application.I would like also to embed a bundled JRE.i managed to achieve it with success from my pc which i have java 1.8.0_161 installed. My problem now is that when i try to execute the .exe from a VM machine that has not java installed i took this error

```
CryptoAlertNews: This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161
```

Why does this happen what I am doing wrong? This is what I have in the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.panos</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.panos</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>com.panos</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.panos.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>l4j-clui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <headerType>console</headerType>
              <outfile>target/CryptoAlertNews.exe</outfile>
              <icon>src/resources/Image/photo.ico</icon>
              <jar>target/com.panos-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
              <errTitle>CryptoAlertNews</errTitle>
              <classPath>
                <mainClass>com.panos.App</mainClass>
                <addDependencies>false</addDependencies>
                <preCp>anything</preCp>
              </classPath>
              <jre>
                <path>src/resources/jre</path>
                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                <bundledJreAsFallback>true</bundledJreAsFallback>
                <minVersion>1.8.0_161</minVersion>
                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
              </jre>
              <versionInfo>
                <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                <copyright>C</copyright>
                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                <internalName>AppName</internalName>
                <originalFilename>CameraControl.exe</originalFilename>
              </versionInfo>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.exe</include>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.crx</include>
          <include>**/*.fxml</include>
          <include>**/*.css</include>
          <include>**/*.json</include>
          <include>**/*.zip</include>
          <include>**/*.dll</include>
          <include>**/*.ico</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be aware that Launch4J does **NOT** embed the JRE, but instead **reference** it on runtime.

The `<path>` contents should be a route that points to a JRE when the *EXE* is executed.

You can distribute your app with a ZIP, and then put a folder `jre` at the root folder, and your `.EXE` in the same folder.

Then your ZIP contents would be as following:

```
|jre (with the contents of the jre uncompressed, including bin directory)
|app.exe
```

You can find a question similar to yours here: [How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j/7582064)