# How to make exe file from JavaFX application with all dependency and JRE.?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, exe, launch4j

I have developed a JavaFX application and I'm new on this platform. Already I had made a .exe file from JAR by Launch4J, but it needs JRE. Is there any way to make .exe file that contains every dependency and JRE bind into that take permission to the user when he/she want to set up the .exe file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10JwLCVH2URlhDINezw2TL8JfklXZscj6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre)

Comment: If you're using Java 14 then check out the `jpackage` tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j)