# Noob figuring out instal4j and intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, launch4j

I am just experimenting to learn how to package and install a java app built on intellij onto a PC.

I built hello world in intellij using "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenJava\openjdk-15.0.2_windows-x64_bin\jdk-15.0.2" and it runs in the development environment.

If I understand Launch4j, I can specify in the JRE tab a bundled JRE so I am not dependant on what is on the target PC.

My question is what do I put in the "Bundled JRE path" box on the JRE tab in Launch4j.  Path to JRE, JDK, openJDK.  Does the path include a file name?  Is it just a directory, the BIN?

a bit lost,
Thanks, Tony

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an example like mine and the solution works for me.

[How to bundle a JRE with Launch4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j)