# I have a problem with sharing my Java application + Launch4j

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, sharing, launch4j

Hello fellow programmers.
I'm going to give you a little bit of context to understand my problem better ;P

I've studied a 2 year vocational training of programming, and now I have to spend 3 months in a company to finally finish.
The company I've been asigned to is not primarly focused in programming, as I'm the only one with a bit of understanding of this subject, so I can't really rely on anyone around here.

Basically, I've been assigned to develop a simple XLSX formatter app with Java.
After a day or two, I finally finished it, but now, I am facing the problem of sharing this app with other people around the office.
I've never shared an app in class, only shared the project with my teacher or classmates, and pressed the compilate button (like in IntelliJ, for example).
After some research, I managed to create the .jar with all the Maven dependencies, and the .exe taking that .jar and copying the path to my JRE (I've duplicated the JRE folder, and I placed it in the project folder)

Then, I made the .zip and sent it to my workmates, but they always get the same error message
`The application requieres a Java Runtime Environment`

What am I doing wrong?

I've installed Java on their PCs and followed a bunch of tutorials, even asked ChatGPT for the specific steps and error.

I'm a native spanish speaker, so sorry for any mistake (cliché)

Comment: The error message itself says the JRE is not installed in the machine where the executable is running. Visit the official Oracle Java website (https://www.java.com) or the Java SE Downloads page (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html) . Select the appropriate installer for the Operating System. Follow the instructions to complete the installation. Try to restart the system once you install the JRE in the machine.

Comment: @RagaSGNur Maybe I am missing something.
She has the same Java version as me, aswell as the same OS.
I've just checked it with java -version in cmd.
The JRE is the same thing as Java right? (Installing Java, gives you the JRE?)

Comment: Yes. java -version will give the Java version and JRE details. I would suggest you go through and understand the difference between JDK, JRE, and JVM. This gives some heads up to understand the development and run time environment of Java. Can you try once to restart the system?

Comment: @RagaSGNur just did, but inspiration has just struck me, and I realized that the JRE path of Launch4j is x/x/jre. That makes it static, right? If I switch devices, it won't find the JRE path, will it?
Should I just change the JRE path and make it dynamic?

Comment: There is a post already available in StackOverflow of "How to bundle JRE with Launch4J". Certainly , you will get valuable insights to your query from the post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j.

Comment: Your problem is resolved ?

Comment: fyi, you can do this  [without using third party tools](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9)